# For what values of $x$ is $\det\begin{bmatrix} x & 5\\ 7 & 10 \end{bmatrix} = 30$?

Tags: matrices, determinant

If I have a matrix of the form
$$
A =
\begin{bmatrix}
4a & b\\ 
4b & a
\end{bmatrix},
$$
then
$$
\left | A \right |
= 4a^{2} - 4b^{2}
= 4\left( a^{2} - b^{2} \right)
= 4 \left( a + b \right) \left( a - b \right).
$$
Now let
$$
D =
\begin{bmatrix}
 x & 5\\ 
 7 & 10
\end{bmatrix}
$$ 
For what values of $x$ is $\left | D \right | = 30$?

Comment: I’m not quite sure what your question is. Is $D$ second matrix, and are you searching for the values of $x$ for which this second matrix has determinant $30$?

Comment: @JendrikStelzner Yes

Comment: I seem to get no relation between both the examples

Comment: determinant of $\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}$ is $ad - bc.$ so set up the equation $10x - 35 = 10$ and solve for $x.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple $10x-35=30$ so $x=6.5$ thats all whats the problem.